# Modifying tree structured data in JavaScript with given condition?

Tags: javascript

I have a tree data like this:

```
var tree = [
  {
    id:"11",
    text: "Parent 1",
    type:"Parent",
    nodeSelected:false,
    nodes: [
      {
        text: "Child 1",
        parentId: "11",
        id:"21",
        nodeSelected:false,
        type: "Child",
        nodes: [
          {
            id:"36",
            text: "Grandchild 1",
            parentId: "21",
            nodeSelected:false,
            nodes:[],
            type: "Grandchild"
          },
          {
            id:"38",
            text: "Grandchild 2",
            parentId: "21",
            nodes:[],
            nodeSelected:false,
            type: "Grandchild"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id:"43",
        text: "Child 2",
        nodeSelected:false,
        parentId:"11",
        type: "Child",
        nodes: [
            {
            id:"52",
            parentId:"43",
            text: "Grandchild 1 of child 2",
            nodeSelected:false,
            nodes:[],
            type: "Grandchild"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id:"46",
    text: "Parent 2",
    nodeSelected:false,
    type: "Parent",
    nodes:[]
  },
  {
    id:"48",
    text: "Parent 3",
    nodeSelected:false,
    type: "Parent",
    node:  [
        {
            id:"70",
            text: "child 3",
            parentId: "48",
            type: "Child",
            nodeSelected:false,
            nodes:[]
        }
    ]
  }
];
```

All of the `nodeSelected` are false.

I have group of Ids in form of an array.

```
groupedIds=["11","21","43","52","48"];
```

I want to do `nodeSelected` property true based on `groupId array` with some condition.

the condition is such that if a parentId is mentioned along with its children ids then `nodeSelected` property of parent should remain
false and child's `nodeSelected` should be true (and its `nodes` `nodeSelected` should also be 'true').
Or else whole parent nodes `nodeSelected` should be true(along with it nodes).

So the result will be like this:

```
var resultArray = [
  {
    id:"11",
    text: "Parent 1",
    type:"Parent",
    nodeSelected:false,
    nodes: [
      {
        text: "Child 1",
        parentId: "11",
        id:"21",
        nodeSelected:true,
        type: "Child",
        nodes: [
          {
            id:"36",
            text: "Grandchild 1",
            parentId: "21",
            nodeSelected:true,  
            type: "Grandchild"
          },
          {
            id:"38",
            text: "Grandchild 2",
            parentId: "21",
            nodeSelected:true,
            type: "Grandchild"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id:"43",
        text: "Child 2",
        nodeSelected:false,
        parentId:"11",
        type: "Child",
        nodes: [
            {
            id:"52",
            parentId:"43",
            text: "Grandchild 1 of child 2",
            nodeSelected:true,
            type: "Grandchild"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id:"46",
    text: "Parent 2",
    nodeSelected:false,
    type: "Parent"
  },
  {
    id:"48",
    text: "Parent 3",
    nodeSelected:true,
    type: "Parent",
    node:  [
        {
            id:"70",
            text: "child 3",
            parentId: "48",
            type: "Child",
            nodeSelected:true
        }
    ]
  }
];
```

(**My try**) Although incomplete but something like this we can do

```
tree.forEach((Parent) => {
            if (groupedIds.includes(Parent.id)) {
                let isSomeChildSelected = Parent.nodes.some((loc) => groupedIds.includes(loc.id));
                if (isSomeChildSelected) {
                    Parent.nodes.forEach((child) => {
                        if (groupedIds.includes(child.id)) {
                            let isSomeGrandChildSelected = child.nodes.some((grandchild) => groupedIds.includes(grandchild.id));
                            if (isSomeGrandChildSelected) {
                                child.nodes.forEach((grandchild) => {
                                    if (groupedIds.includes(grandchild.id)) {
                                        grandchild.isSelected = true;
                                    }
                                })
                            } else {
                                child.isSelected = true;
                                child.nodes.forEach((grandchild) => {
                                    grandchild.isSelected = true;
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    Parent.isSelected = true;
                    Parent.nodes.forEach((child) => {
                        child.isSelected = true;
                        child.nodes.forEach((grandchild) => {
                            grandchild.isSelected = true;
                        })
                    })
                }
            }
        })
```

The above tried method solves the issue to some extent, but it is a bit complex.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: *"I tried it by looping the whole tree and checking if its Id present or not and then changing the property but I couldn't get it done. "* Post JavaScript as a [mcve]

Comment: @zer00ne even if I share what I tried here won't help other developers.

Comment: It allows us to help you resolve your issues. If we see your code then we have a starting point to which we can instruct, advise, and assist you efficiently. If we were to start code from scratch, how much of it do we need to explain to you? How would we know whether you are proficient and knowledgeable in certain aspects or not. At this point, I have no clue as to whether you know how to use a loop or if you are aware of the difference between an array and an object literal.

Comment: @zer00ne, sure let me share what I tried here.

Comment: Have you looked into a word called `recursion`?

Comment: @gorak it looks as if 21 and 43 are identical in the hierarchy (children of 11) and conditions (as I vaguely understand them) are met by both, yet 21 is `nS` and 43 is `!nS`. When you say, *"`parentId` is mentioned"*, do you mean an id value in `groupedIds` array?

Comment: @gorak continuing on my previous comment, is 43 `!ns` because 52 is in `groupedIds`? Also, 21 is `nS` because 38 and 36 are not in `groupedIds`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives me output what I want(with recursion):

```js
var tree = [
  {
    id:"11",
    text: "Parent 1",
    type:"Parent",
    nodeSelected:false,
    nodes: [
      {
        text: "Child 1",
        parentId: "11",
        id:"21",
        nodeSelected:false,
        type: "Child",
        nodes: [
          {
            id:"36",
            text: "Grandchild 1",
            parentId: "21",
            nodeSelected:false,
            nodes:[],
            type: "Grandchild"
          },
          {
            id:"38",
            text: "Grandchild 2",
            parentId: "21",
            nodes:[],
            nodeSelected:false,
            type: "Grandchild"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id:"43",
        text: "Child 2",
        nodeSelected:false,
        parentId:"11",
        type: "Child",
        nodes: [
            {
            id:"52",
            parentId:"43",
            text: "Grandchild 1 of child 2",
            nodeSelected:false,
            nodes:[],
            type: "Grandchild"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id:"46",
    text: "Parent 2",
    nodeSelected:false,
    type: "Parent",
    nodes:[]
  },
  {
    id:"48",
    text: "Parent 3",
    nodeSelected:false,
    type: "Parent",
    nodes:  [
        {
            id:"70",
            text: "child 3",
            parentId: "48",
            type: "Child",
            nodeSelected:false,
            nodes:[]
        }
    ]
  }
];

groupedIds=["11","21","43","52","48"];

var selectAllNode=array=> array.forEach((value)=>{ value.nodeSelected=true; value.nodes? selectAllNode(value.nodes) : [] });

var getFilteredData = array => array.forEach((ele)=>{
if(groupedIds.includes(ele.id)){
 let isSomeSelected = ele.nodes.some((val)=>groupedIds.includes(val.id));
 if(isSomeSelected){
  getFilteredData(ele.nodes);
  } else {
  ele.nodeSelected=true;
  selectAllNode(ele.nodes);
  }
 } 
});


getFilteredData(tree);
console.log(tree);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to do it for you (not out of malice, just because I'm not 100% sure I understand the question!), but I'll hopefully give you a big point in the right direction.

When traversing trees, 90% of the time you need something called recursion. Recursion looks like this:

```
function walk(items){
  items.forEach(items => {
    if(item.hasChildrenOrSomething){
      // notice the function calls itself:
      walk(item.children);
    }

    // Do something with item
  });
}

walk(tree);
```

There is one important thing to note here, which is that if you do some logic *after* calling the function inside itself, all the children of the current item will have that logic applied. So, here we go – in your case you want something like this:

```
const walk = (branch) => {
  branch.forEach(node => {
    // Check if this object even has children:
    if(node.hasOwnProperty('nodes') && node.nodes.length){
      walk(node.nodes);
      // Do your node.nodes.every check here
    }
    // Now check if this is in the array
  });
}

walk(tree);
```

If you've used recursion before, sorry, this whole post was probably just super patronising and has missed the point of your question. If you haven't, then can I just say I am a) jealous of you for getting to experience the feeling of something so elegant for the first time and b) sorry for you for having to unravel the mind boggling nature of them.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I'll definitely try it.

Comment: If you get further with it, then get stuck (and I have time) I'd be happy to take a look at the "next attempt" of your code

Comment: Surely, I'll update my question along with the latest try.